# Wait for the service before ngOnInit

Tags: angular

My component is subscribed to a service ServiceA

```
constructor(private service: ServiceA) {
    this.service.initComplete.subscribe(() => this.initialize());
}
```

And I have ngOnInit() implementation.

However, I need the service.initComplete to complete first before my component is initialized.  How should I do it?

Comment: if you are using the router you can use the resolver

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Ritesh he is trying to wait for the service before ngOnInit. Obviously has some logic that needs to be executed before ngOnInit

Comment: @SeaBiscuit Exactly, then why he just can't provide the data that his component needs from the service, I mean he can have this service in the parent component and get the data from there and pass to the child.. why to wait befor ngOnInit.. ? That's why I asked what he want to achieve? There are always a better way to achieve the stuff rather than just solving the need of OP.